# myErrorHandler getting error

Tags: php

I am getting following errors messages:

> Notice: Use of undefined constant myErrorHandler - assumed 'myErrorHandler' in C:\xampp\htdocs\Webpage\Security\functions.php on line 78

and

> Warning: set_error_handler() expects the argument (myErrorHandler) to be a valid callback in C:\xampp\htdocs\Webpage\Security\functions.php on line 78

I cant figure out what I need to do to correct the error. I want the function myErrorHandler to handle all the error's on the webpage.

```
function DB_Connect() 
{
    static $conn;
   if (!$conn) {
        mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
        $conn = mysqli_connect(DEF_Server,DEF_User,DEF_Password,DEF_Database);
    }
    return $conn;
}

set_error_handler(myErrorHandler);
function myErrorHandler($errno, $errstr, $errfile, $errline) 
{
    error_log("$errstr in $errfile:$errline");
    header('HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error', TRUE, 500);
    readfile($NAV_DB_Error500);
    exit;
}
```

I have fixed following per "SebTM":

```
set_error_handler("myErrorHandler");
function myErrorHandler($errno, $errstr, $errfile, $errline) 
{
    error_log("$errstr in $errfile:$errline");
    header('HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error', TRUE, 500);
    readfile($NAV_DB_Error500);
    exit;
}
```

I am now getting following error, it removed the Notice, but the Warning is still there:

> Warning: set_error_handler() expects the argument (myErrorHandler) to be a valid callback in C:\xampp\htdocs\Webpage\Security\functions.php on line 78

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass the name of the function (after declaration) to "set_error_handler" as string e.g.

`set_error_handler("myErrorHandler");`

An error-handler should also return "true" as boolean to avoid internal php error-handling!